# Cluster table by nested fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I have worked with partitioned and clustered tables before. I always use simple fields for this, but now I have the necessity to cluster my table by some nested fields. This is a reduced example of my schema:

```
id
timestamp
source
|-email
|-service
|-country
```

I do not have any problem for the partitioning as the `timestamp` field is a simple one. However, I would like to cluster the table by `source.service` and `source.country` fields and I do not know how to refer to those nested columns when declaring the clusters on table creation.

I have search over other related questions and documentation on Internet but I have not found any solution. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partitioning column must be a top-level field.
You cannot use a leaf field from a RECORD (STRUCT) as the partitioning column.
The partitioning column must be either a scalar DATE, TIMESTAMP, or DATETIME column. While the mode of the column can be REQUIRED or NULLABLE, it cannot be REPEATED (array-based).
Check all [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#limitations)

Similar [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#limitations) for clustering
Clustering columns must be top-level, non-repeated columns of one of the following types:

```
DATE
BOOL
GEOGRAPHY
INT64
NUMERIC
BIGNUMERIC
STRING
TIMESTAMP
DATETIME
```